# Windows services not visible remotely

Tags: windows, powershell, networking, service

I'm struggling to figure out what is going on, but it has a pretty widespread effect on a system I'm working with.

I have several machines running a service, but when I try to query the service (both in .net and in powershell) the service is not found. When I connect to the machine via RDP, the service shows up. I've already confirmed that I had permissions on the service, including granting explicit permissions to the service for my user using subinacl.

I do get a result back from get-service -computername $server but it doesn't list the service I'm looking for. Is there a group policy or windows configuration that I'm missing here? Why would some services show up remotely but not all of them?

Any tips/advice on what to look for would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: Using this command:

```
get-Service -computername $servername | Export-Csv C:\temp\Local.csv -notypeinformation
```

**On the machine** yields the following file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aXvIgWT4NU2EN4j14JlxrY-jHGp-hG2Q

Running the same command remotely against the machine yields the following file: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=16NvRgrQsSGc9CKlqmIqntLy1bkLMl5tJ

**EDIT2:**

Command:

```
Get-Service -Computername $servername -Name 'AdobeARMservice'
```

Running Remotely Result:

```
Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name
 'AdobeARMservice'. At line:1 char:1
 + Get-Service -Computername $servername -Name 'AdobeARMservice'
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (AdobeARMservice:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandExcep
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

Running Locally Result:

```
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  AdobeARMservice    Adobe Acrobat Update Service
```

**Edit3:**

This issue can also be seen in the microsoft service list.

While locally on the machine:[image: LocalServiceImage]

While remote: [image: RemoteServiceImage]

Comment: You need to provide sample commands and output (nobody can see your screen).

Comment: Using this command: "get-Service -computername $servername | Export-Csv C:\temp\Local.csv -notypeinformation" on the machine yields the following file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aXvIgWT4NU2EN4j14JlxrY-jHGp-hG2Q running the same command remotely against the machine yields the following file:https://drive.google.com/open?id=16NvRgrQsSGc9CKlqmIqntLy1bkLMl5tJ

Comment: I can't access those links. Please update your question with a _short sample script that contains only the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem_. Also post the _text_ (not a picture) of the _exact error message(s) you get_ (if any).

Comment: I believe the issue is a group policy that is preventing specific services from being seen remotely. Some service show up, others dont. I've updated my OP (see edit 2) with an example using AdobeARMService

Comment: I would check the permissions of the service(s) in question. This would seem to be a superuser/serverfault question rather than a stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 1):

The powershell documentation for [get-service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service?view=powershell-6) says:

> This cmdlet can display services only when the current user has
>   permission to see them. If this cmdlet does not display services, you
>   might not have permission to see them.

I would therefore assume that your remote user is a different user than the local user.

Comment: I think everyone is getting a little hung up on the language. This isn't an issue with powershell, its an issue with windows configurations. This issue can be seen in the windows service list as well as in powershell and .net code. See edit 3 (screenshots)

Answer (score 0):

if you truly have access rights, you could just do this instead

```
invoke-command -computername $servername -scriptblock {get-service} | export-csv C:\temp\Local.csv -notypeinformation
```

Comment: I'm simply using this powershell to test. The problem is the .net code checks for service status and if its not shown, the process fails. I need to address the issue not code around it unfortunately. I did try out of curiosity and I get a permission error, but I'm a domain admin.

Comment: Well the permission error is likely your cause. Is that computer on the domain etc...

Comment: Yes, the machines are on the same domain. When I grant local admin, the issue goes away, but given that these are app servers, I cant be granting local admin. This is why I'm looking for the group policy or some other item in AD that does this. I've already granted full access to the services I'm trying to reach for the AD group but it still doesn't show up, while other services, where I haven't granted extra permissions on don't show up.

Comment: correction... local admin doesn't fix it... domain admin does

Comment: I think you'll receive much better help on [serverfault](http://www.serverfault.com), As they are better suited to this question. It seems to be some mundane server config that we aren't thinking of.